I need help with the 4:1 MUX select probes?
I am making a DC motor (motor A) that is working under the following conditions:
a) We have a 5 Hz clock signal,
b) stops for 2 seconds,
c) turns right for 4 seconds,
d) stops for 3 seconds,
e) turns right for 5 seconds,
f) repeats.
I need help with the circuit that I've built. I used 4:1 MUX. I don't know what to do with the second 'select' probe.


How is wired the first signal on the left FF (high-left D input of the picture)? Input is wired with input ?

The four AND gates at the bottom of your drawing will always output a LOW/zero as one input is LOW. You need to use both select inputs on the mux to be able to select between the four inputs to it.

NB: the upper inputs AND gates are wired together ... How can you change the digital value of inputs ?

I'm afraid that your approach will not work because the set of clock dividers do not work as you expect. Start with a diagram showing their output signal over several of their periods. -- You can use any digital simulator to check your design ideas.
